# Average of 10 days in a month using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch values for each day for the last 2 years. I need to get the average for 10 days of the month. Like average from Sep1 - Sep10, Sept 11 - 20 etc...

The values are in a fact table and my objective is to create an aggregate fact table out of it. The fields in fact table are - Location Key, Time Key and Value.

The `time_dim` table has the calender date and `time_key`.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Appreciate your help.

Arun

Sample data

```
Location_Key----Time_Key----Value
2345------------414---------300
333-------------413---------400
1---------------2346--------566
14--------------1987--------900
2379------------111---------250
346-------------110---------1125
188-------------333---------567
187-------------422---------333
21--------------789---------170
211-------------2-----------900
```

Time dim has Calender date like `2013.01.01`, `2013.01.02`, `2013.01.03`..... etc.
I need to get the avg for 10 days.

The sample data in time_dim attached

```
TIME_KEY    CAL_DATE    DAY_OF_MONTH    WEEK_NUMBER MONTH_NUMBER    WEEK    DEKADE  DEKADE_NUMBER   MONTH   YEAR_MONTH  JULIAN  YEAR    DEKADE_KEY  MONTH_DESC
413 2013.01.01  1   1   1   2013W00 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 1   2013    2628    2013M01
103 2013.01.02  2   1   1   2013W00 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 2   2013    2628    2013M01
683 2013.01.03  3   1   1   2013W00 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 3   2013    2628    2013M01
414 2013.01.04  4   1   1   2013W00 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 4   2013    2628    2013M01
207 2013.01.05  5   1   1   2013W00 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 5   2013    2628    2013M01
684 2013.01.06  6   1   1   2013W00 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 6   2013    2628    2013M01
415 2013.01.07  7   2   1   2013W01 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 7   2013    2628    2013M01
6   2013.01.08  8   2   1   2013W01 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 8   2013    2628    2013M01
685 2013.01.09  9   2   1   2013W01 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 9   2013    2628    2013M01
416 2013.01.10  10  2   1   2013W01 2013D01 1   Jan 2013M01 10  2013    2628    2013M01
686 2013.01.11  11  2   1   2013W01 2013D02 2   Jan 2013M01 11  2013    2629    2013M01
208 2013.01.12  12  2   1   2013W01 2013D02 2   Jan 2013M01 12  2013    2629    2013M01
687 2013.01.13  13  2   1   2013W01 2013D02 2   Jan 2013M01 13  2013    2629    2013M01
417 2013.01.14  14  3   1   2013W02 2013D02 2   Jan 2013M01 14  2013    2629    2013M01
104 2013.01.15  15  3   1   2013W02 2013D02 2   Jan 2013M01 15  2013    2629    2013M01
```

SQL query

```
select  min(cal_date), max(cal_date), sum(daily_weather), location_key, dekade_key
from 
(select t.*,(row_number() over (order by cal_date) -
              row_number() over (partition by daily_weather order by cal_date)
             ) as grpid
      from aggr_fact_testing t
     ) t
group by grpid, cal_date,location_key,dekade_key
```

Comment: How about some ddl and sample data? I can think about 5 or 6 pretty easy possibilities but it depends on your data structures etc...sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start

Comment: Since you already have a time dimension, can't you just join the fact table with it, and use a range of 10 days for the join?

Comment: I tried joining time_dim with the fact table but stuck on how to dynamically calculate for 10 days of each month. Edited the question for sample data.

Comment: JamesZ, how do you do that. Thats what i am exactly looking for. Sorry i am not much familiar with SQL.

Comment: I would simply slice your date into Year, Month and Day, then slice Day into 1-10, 11-20 and 21-31, then group by these values and do your aggregations. Might work?

Comment: And for February the last range would be 8 or 9 days? And for Jan/Mar/May/Jul/Aug/Oct/Dec the last range would be 11 days?

Comment: I have already created the time_dim in that way only with calender date, week, month, year and days. Now the second part how to capture only 10 days? Whats the query?

Comment: Also how will you link this with the .location_key in the fact table because one location and one time key can have more than 10 values.

Comment: You should provide sample data stored in `time_dim` table (which corresponds to `time_key` field in `location` table).

Comment: Forgot to mention that both time key and location key are surrogate keys or identity inserts. Sample data in the edited question.

Comment: @Arun.K where is your query, post a query so we can see what do you have so far

Comment: @Dn24Z i am doing this in a ETL tool which is similar to SSIS, so SQL server code should work. I got a query (edited the question) from stack over flow, which is similar to my requirement but the ETL tool is throwing an error saying empty column names. Can you tell me where's it wrong?

Comment: @Dn24Z i am doing this in a ETL tool which is similar to SSIS, so SQL server code should work. I got a query (edited the question) from stack over flow, but its not showing the right value. Both minimum and maximum dates are coming same. Can you tell me where's it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like...

```
SELECT t.Location_Key, td.MONTH_NUMBER, td.YEAR, CASE WHEN (td.DAY_OF_MONTH <= 10) THEN '1-10' ELSE CASE WHEN (td.DAY_OF_MONTH <= 20) THEN '11-20' ELSE '21-31' END END, AVG(t.Value) 
FROM yourTable t
INNER JOIN time_dim td ON td.TIME_KEY = t.Time_key
GROUP BY t.Location_Key, td.MONTH_NUMBER, td.YEAR, CASE WHEN (td.DAY_OF_MONTH <= 10) THEN '1-10' ELSE CASE WHEN (td.DAY_OF_MONTH <= 20) THEN '11-20' ELSE '21-31' END END
```

Haven't tested it because I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for exactly. Check it out and comment.

Comment: Thanks @Pinx0. This works, i may have to tweek a liitle bit though.